# Compressing an image to make it less than 4KB

Tags: image, image-processing, compression

I have an image of a person and I want to compress it to make it less than 4KB. I need to compress it and still have the face of the person recognizable even if the image will shrink.

Comment: Please share the image so we can see if it is JPEG or PNG, colour or black and white, how big it is in pixels, whether the face fills the frame...

Comment: Further, do you mean you want the image to be recognisable as being a face? Or recognisable as being the face of a specific person?

Comment: The initial size of the image is variable and its colored. I want to compress it and resize it to 70×70 pixel and make it grayscale. But the challenge is to make it less than 1KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Theresa May at 142kB:

[image]

and resized to 72x72 and converted to greyscale and reduced to 2kB with **ImageMagick** at the command line:

```
convert original.jpg -resize 72x72 -colorspace gray -define jpeg:extent=2kb result.jpg
```

[image]

I can still recognise her.

---

Here is some other guy reduced to 1kB and I can still recognise him too:

[image]

### [image]

**ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Bindings are available for Python, PHP, Ruby, Javascript, Perl etc.

---

If you had further knowledge about your images, or your recognition algorithm, you may be able to do better. For example, if you knew that the centre of the image was more important than the edges, you could slightly blur, or reduce contrast in relatively unimportant areas and use the available space for more details in the important areas.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Setchell has the right idea. But I might suggest one potential minor improvement. Remove any meta data including profiles, EXIF data etc. You can do that by either adding -strip

```
convert input.jpg -strip -resize 72x72 -colorspace gray -define jpeg:extent=2kb result.jpg
```

or by using -thumbnail rather than -resize. The former automatically does the strip.

```
convert input.jpg -thumbnail 72x72 -colorspace gray -define jpeg:extent=2kb result.jpg
```